# Regex pattern for extraction of double-quoted and non-quoted strings Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

im desperately trying to extract double quoted and non-quoted words from following string (Please note the single quotes around):

```
'"Cloud Technology" Foundation "Board"'
```

Desired groups are:

1. "Cloud Technology"
2. Foundation
3. "Board"

I came up with this pattern `(?:\"(.*?)\")|(?:\s(\S*?)\s)` have a look in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/OT1Tjv/1)

But the pattern doesnt works if the string would be for example `'"Cloud Technology" Foundation'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```js
console.log(`'"Cloud Technology" Foundation "Board"'`.match(/"[^"]+"|[^\s']+/g))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2cpLaO/1). *Details*:

- `"[^"]+"` - `"`, zero or more chars other than `"` and then a `"` char
- `|` - or
- `[^\s']+` - one or more chars other than whitespace and `'` chars.

Comment: thank you very much! this works as desired for a arbitrary list of words in double-quotes and non-quoted words. only downside was that adding groups around the pattern did not work as desired but i can work with the full matches

Answer (score 0):

What's about to add to second group charakter `'` as additional possible end (or beginner):

`(?:\"(.*?)\")|(?:[\s\'](\S*?)[\s\'])`

Comment: this is only matching < "Cloud> and < Foundation>

Comment: Yes. I see. Thx for Feedback. Must have been somehow to fast yesterday ... but I believe to remember I had tested :-/